I am trying to push code to remote repo ($ git push -u origin master) but getting error like "fatal: protocol 'git@https' is not supported"
I am trying to push code to remote repo ($ git push -u origin master) but getting error like "fatal: protocol 'git@https' is not supported"
enter image description here
Could you please help with this error ?
Note  I have reset "git url" by typing (not copy pasted).
it should push code to remote repo.

Don't post text as image, post as text.

Remove git@ from the URL, just git remote set-url origin https://github.com/AnilGarad304/Selenium_Demo_2024.git will do

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
